# ACF Custom Field Type, 'input_admin_enqueue_scripts' call back function not firing

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using their template, to create my custom field type as what they have recommend here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/

this is my scenario, I want to fetch youtube details via youtube id, using youtube api and display the results after.

I have below fields, to input the youtube id and submit after:

- YouTube ID(input type text)
- Submit Button(input type submit)

I will populate below fields after submit:

- Title(input type text)
- Description(input type text)
- Thumbnail URL(input type text)
- Upload Date(input type text)
- Duration minute(input type number)
- Duration seconds(input type number)

To do this, I need to do an ajax request when the submit button has been click, but I have trouble getting the field.js to work, I am not sure how to call the 'input_admin_enqueue_scripts' callback function, I am expecting that this would be triggered automatically, I have also tried to change the version, but its not working, can someone guide me on this?

Comment: This is not yet a question. You must have some Javascript code for the "Get YouTube Detail" button to work with, correct? What did you tried and how did it not work?

Comment: Also please share any source code related to this.

Comment: Never seen anyone extending `acf_field` before. Is the `input_admin_enqueue_scripts` supposed to be called automatically somehow based on that? Because normally, you'd need to add your own callback function to the hook of that name, https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-input-admin_enqueue_scripts/#example

Comment: @CBroe I am using their, template as what they have mention here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/

Comment: Whether or not it gets called automatically should be easy enough to verify, if you just put `die('input_admin_enqueue_scripts was called!');` at the start of the method - and then see if you get that text shown in the frontend and then nothing more after that, or not.

Comment: I have confirmed that the method gets called, and the script gets loaded but for some reason, the console log is not working

Comment: I have change the, url to plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) and its working

Comment: Check console to see if the scripts are loaded correctly. It doesn't make sense if the script is loaded but `console.log()` in it is not running. Possible issue: (1) incorrect script path; (2) syntax error in the script; (3) your script has bug.

Comment: @KoalaYeung it is incorrect script path

Answer (score 0):

I have change the, url to plugin_dir_url( **FILE** ) and its working, field.js and field.css is now being called!